# Using NET::SMTP in Perl to send .OFT templates

Tags: perl

I currently have a working Perl code that fires off an email to the correct email address with my generic subject and content.

However, currently whenever a new user starts, we fire off a premade .oft template that says everything that they need to know. The .oft is stored on our server. I was wondering is there a way to alter the perl code to make it so it takes the to: but uses the .oft template to make the rest of the email??

so basically

```
    $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('smtp.blah');
    $smtp->('no-replay@blah.com');
    $smtp->to('$personEmail');
    $smtp->data();
    $smtp->datasend($locationOfOftTemplate);
    $smtp->dataend();
    $smtp->quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no module for handling this proprietary format. Instead, translate it to a standard templating system:

```
my $template = <<'TEMPLATE';
Good morning, [% name %]!

Today is your first day at work. You have already received your universal login
credentials:

    [% ldap_user %]
    [% ldap_pass %]

It works for authenticating at the Web proxy, mail system, Jabber and internal
services. Change the password ASAP: <[% ldap_web %]>

-- 
Yours sincerely, the greeting daemon
TEMPLATE

use Text::Xslate qw();
my $text = Text::Xslate->new(syntax => 'TTerse')->render_string($template, {
    name => 'New Bee',
    ldap_user => 'nbee',
    ldap_pass => 'CON-GLOM-O',
    ldap_web => 'http://192.168.0.1:8080/',
});
```

Use a MIME toolkit to create emails. HTML/multipart/attachments are easy with
[Courriel::Builder](http://p3rl.org/Courriel%3a%3aBuilder):

```
use Courriel::Builder;

my $email = build_email(
    subject('Welcome'),
    from('no-reply@example.com'),
    to('…'),
    plain_body($text),
);
```

Finally, send it using the high-level library [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender) that gives you nice error checking and allows you to easily switch out transports - run local delivery for testing.

```
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP qw();
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    sendmail(
        $email,
        {
            transport => Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
                host => 'smtp.example.invalid',
            })
        }
    );
} catch {
    warn "sending failed: $_";
};
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing for this? I can get the entire .oft template to parse in to an email subject like it's suppose to. The only issue I'm running in to now appears to be a cody issue. The entire .oft body looks similar to this...

        ÐÏ à¡± á> þÿ     

It appears to be a UTF-8 encoding issue, but I'm struggling to convert everything.

Comment: [Open a new topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your follow-up question. Provide your input data and code there.