# Using NET::SMTP in Perl to send .OFT templates appears to be UTF-8 issue

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I currently have script that creates a new SMTP and fires off an automated email using a pre-made .oft Microsoft tempate. Here is the code for the actual sending of the email.

```
    use strict;
    use Net::SMTP;
    my $email = "blah@blah.com";
    my $emailTemplate = "C:/place/where/template/goes/template.oft;


    open FILE, "$template" or die $!;
    binmode(FILE);
    my $data = do { local $/, <FILE> };
    close FILE;


    $smtp = NET::SMTP->('smtp.blah.com');
    $smtp->mail{'EMAILGROUP');
    $smtp->to('person@blah.com');

    $smtp->data();
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: This is the subject");
    $smtp->datasend("$data");

    $smtp->dataend();
    $smtp->quit;
```

This results in the following getting sent to the user

```
    ÐÏ à¡± á> þÿ        
    þÿÿÿ
    ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ        ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ        ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ        ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ        ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿRoot
```

and it keeps going. The .oft file is in UTF-8 and I just think it's not converting properly. Is there something I can do to convert all of this over before the actual sending of the email?

Comment: The results you should be getting is multiple syntax errors.

Comment: [Yesterday I asked you to provide the input file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598326/using-netsmtp-in-perl-to-send-oft-templates#comment25809441_17609506) Upload the template, or provide a hexdump of the variable `$data`.

Comment: $data is just a normal Outlook email saved off as a .oft file. Nothing special about it similar to 

"Hello, Welcome to blah, for more information clikc this link. blah"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MIME::Lite : Sending emails with defined charset or/and attachments

Use module [`MIME::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) instead of module [`Net::SMTP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libnet/Net/SMTP.pm).
It will ease task of setting proper MIME headers e.g. declaring charset.

```
$msg->set("Content-type" => "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

[`MIME::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm) can send email via SMTP (and other means).

Comment: So I am using this and the heart of the template looks correct, but above and below it is has hundreds of lines of this.... <br/>

` ࡱ >         Root Entry   
-5Li 
@*__properties_version1.00 a0 __nameid_version1.0(    ,Li -5Li __substg1.0_0E04001E*  
     fq 
  
    a           ¬ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@*  
     fq `

Comment: Actually making the Type "text/html" make the main part how it's suppose to. There is still all the gibberish on the top and bottom of the email that I'm not sure what it's from

Comment: The gibberish may be caused by *.oft file not being "clean html". Could you use "pure" html as template file? [May be with some special markup to be replaced/customized by your perl script]

Comment: Just changing the template to an .html template worked. Should have figured that one out on my own haha. Thanks for all of your help! I have got this working correctly now!